# Simple fitdistr(rnorm(100), "normal") fails with "error in substring"

Tags: r, debugging

I am trying to do a simple use of the *fitdistr* function from the *MASS* library and it is failing in the following way:

```
fitdistr(rnorm(100), "normal")

"Error in substring("      ", 1L, (nchar(ans[2L, ]) - nchar(dn[[2L]]))%/%2)
: 4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
```

I have updated RStudio and all my R packages but still no success.

Can someone advise how to fix this problem?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.2 (unknown)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] MASS_7.3-45

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.0
```

Comment: Didn't get that error. Use `sessionInfo()` to provide more information on setup.

Comment: Yes, I have tested this in another laptop (same RStudio version, with updated packages) and it works. I'm going to write the sessionInfo() output up there